# Find longest initial substring which renders in a limited width

Tags: c#, .net, word-wrap

I have a long string, ex: "Please help me to solve this problem."
This string is so long to fit in a width of 100 pixels.
I need to get a substring of this string and substring will fit in 100 pixels. Ex: substring "Please help me to sol" is fit in 100 pixels.

Please help me how to estimate a substring like this. Thanks.

My application is Win Forms and C#.

Comment: Are you running in a partial trust environment, or can you call unmanaged code?

Comment: @Lu Lu: there are 3 good answers here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, the Win32 API has a function designed exactly for this: [GetTextExtentExPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144935(v=VS.85).aspx)

P/invoke declaration: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetTextExtentExPoint.html

Comment: Actually it looks like the `System.Drawing.Graphics` class has a similar overload for `MeasureString`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957webty(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: So it does.  Which one of us should put that link on the pinvoke.net page (under "equivalent managed API")?

Comment: ooooooh. Nice on the measurestring overload, never noticed.

Comment: Ok, that link has been added to pinvoke.net now, to save time for the next person who thinks about using `GetTextExtentExPoint` from .NET

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use [TextRenderer::MeasureText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

this should work... not really tested and no optimisations, though

```
var g = Graphics.FromImage(someimage); // or any from hwnd etc... should use your panel/whatever
var f = new Font("YOURFONT", 12f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); // replace with your vals
var yourtext = "yourtextyourtextyourtextyourtextyourtext";
while (g.MeasureString(yourtext, f).Width > 100)
    yourtext = yourtext.Remove(yourtext.Length - 2, 1);
```

Comment: I think it should be g.MeasureString(yourtext... instead of g.MeasureString("yourtext"...

Comment: `yourtext` should not be quoted in the while condition.

Comment: This seems like it would be very slow for strings much longer than 100 characters.

Comment: I need the best solution with optimization. Thanks.

Comment: @juharr and Kevin - thanks. @Michael - pixels, not characters.

Comment: @Lu Lu - are you for real? It's a (probably) working solution. There are many optimisations possible (like, guess the average width of chars and do a first-pass substring before the loop). Do what fits your needs. This is 'help me solve a problem' not 'write my program for me for free'. Also, the time to run this code is trivial regardless, even on lengthy strings.

Comment: A binary search will help you find the optimal break point quickly, even for very long strings.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are looking for is a good estimate, you might first measure the width of a representative string to determine the average character width of your font once.  A good representative might not be just the alphabet; you might look for a character frequency histogram to get a better average width.

```
string Representative = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
float CharacterWidth;

using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(0, 0))
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
using(Font f = /* some font definition */)
{
    CharacterWidth = g.MeasureString(Representative, f).Width / Representative.Length;
}
```

Then use that to estimate how many characters would fit within N pixels.

```
string Text = ...

int DisplayWidth = 100;

int FitLength = Math.Min(Text.Length, (int)(DisplayWidth / CharacterWidth));
string FitText = Text.Substring(0, FitLength);
```

Comment: @abatishchev: Thanks for the edit, I didn't realize you could stack "using" statements in that way. How convenient!